# How to repair void in edge of subfloor from rot?

Tags: bathroom, subfloor

Started what I thought was an easy job of placing "peel and stick" tile and grout in my downstairs bathroom, but that was until I removed the quarter round at the base of the tub.

[image: dryrot]

It is not all the way through. I've been under the house to check, plus I cannot poke through it with a screwdriver.

What can I do here? It is such a small area that I'm not enthusiastic about laying new subfloor.

Comment: that is really not as bad as most I have worked on. Since you want to put tile down I would fill the area with thinset or a mortar, let it cure and your base for the tile should be fine. It looks like you have removed all the bad wood so you should be good to go.

Comment: The tile I'm using is vinyl stick-on. I definitely would like to keep most of the laminate as it would be ideal padding. You're the second person to suggest doing a fill. Someone told me to do self-leveling compound.

Comment: In a bathroom that's not likely "dry rot". It's just rot (due to moisture). Make sure you address that problem as well.

Comment: @isherwood I know where the moisture came from. A toddler bathed in this bathtub and had a tendency to splash. There was an attempt to caulk, but it was most likely too late.

Answer (score 1):

Yick, we had something similar but worse.  I:
Cut out whatever subfloor was gone.
The joists were stained and powdery looking in spots, so to prevent any mold colonies I painted those up to the edges of the remaining subfloor material with Kilz.  When that was dry, I screwed in pieces of matching plywood to replace the gaps, noting that I made sure to have all edges secured over the joists - no pieces with hanging edges short of the joists.
I then painted everything I replaced on the exposed subfloor with Kilz, going on the idea that if it seeped once, it could seep again someday.

(Replacing the entire floor - once I had 1/2" plywood down, replaced where needed, I went over that with 1/4", which made sure no repair seams showed through the flooring over time.)